# Magnetic field is conservative?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is a magnetic field conservative or non-conservative and how is the induced electric field non-conservative?

Comment: [This](https://www.quora.com/Is-magnetic-field-conservative-or-non-conservative) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic field is obviously non-conservative as it has a [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29). Moving wires with current around eachother you will get a periodical movement, while it generates (or uses) energy continously.

The reasoning is the same for induced electric field.

This is why electric motors can work.